# How to create a python program with elevated privileges?

Tags: python, windows

I am creating a python program for which I want to create the .exe and install inside the program files directory of the windows. The program is built for scraping and hence generates some output files after scraping. The problem arises while generating those files inside the program files directory as it requires program to run with the elevated privileges. Currently the solution I have is to right click the .exe file and select the option run as administrator but I know you can make an .exe to always ask the user to run it as administrator. How can I do that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why put it in the windows directory, just create a dir and place the python script/exe there and add the dir to the PATH, unless you want to add this on somebody's else computer

Comment: there is a very good reason why programs should not be allowed write in the windows directory: security

Comment: @rioV8 the author wants to install to 'program files', not windows

Comment: Why not write to 'Documents' dir? There is no reason to use protected paths. Please share your code

Comment: @pierpy same argument goes for `program files`. years ago it was possible but for security reasons it is not allowed anymore

Comment: @rioV8 that's right, I know. it was just not to mislead the author

Comment: Thanks guys for the reply, I took the advice of @rioV8 and changed the working directory to Users/Public. Thanks for the advice.